# Xtext Integration with GMF

Tags: eclipse, xtext, eclipse-gmf

I see xtex can be integrated with gmf, but I can't find any tutorial, explanation or example code.

Is there any explanation about how to do this?

And I want to ask... Can I create an xtext project and then with same metamodel (ecore) can I create a gmf project?  I want to sencron the 2 projects?

Because I want the users who want to use my tool can be work with textual, Graphical syntax or both at the same time.

So anyone can help me with that?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [1] for a solution using Epsilon's Eugenia

[1] http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/472225/1036564/#msg_1036564

Comment: it worked fine but when i create element from .mydsl file my eclipse give me  'code' Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.contentAssist.proposals: {ActionHandler(org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction@3aa0b6d7)} vs {org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.handler.ContentAssistHandler@264af45e} 'code'  error. But anyway it works. U know why this error have been occured ?

Comment: and i want to ask u can i use embedded xtext in gmf ? On property view or right click content and write xtext dsl code ?